# Openswan not updating the routing table

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I have a couple problems that I'm trying to find solutions to. I have Openswan and ASA configure as a IPSec VPN tunnel and the connection is established and working, but with some little problems. The topology is looking like this:

> MyPC
>   (192.168.0.0/23)<-->ASA==IPSecVPNTunnel==Openswan(192.168.10.0/23)<->Server1,2,3,4,5

So `ping` from myPC to one of the servers is working. But `ping` from the servers or Openswan is not working. What I have done for now is using `iptables` (POSTROUTING,MASQUERADE,enabled forwarding etc.).

Looking at the routing table it appears that I'm missing the route that Openswan should've added.

```
Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask        Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
1.1.1.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         1.1.1.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

And I don't know why it's not adding. When I try to add it manually, it still is not working. Any solutions about this or hints?

Also, this is all installed on CentOS with two physical interfaces eth0 (public) eth2 ( local ) and this is what I found in the log files:

```
Sep 11 05:36:09 localhost pluto[7516]: "infra" #6: route-client output: /usr/libexec/ipsec/_updown.netkey: doroute `ip route replace 192.168.0.0/23 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.10.1' failed (RTNETLINK answers: No such process)
```

Comment: do you have some NAT configured? The traffic that goes trough the VPN must be excluded from NAT. As for pinging from the openswan itself you must use the -I option to specify the inside IP address.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant configuration of the Cisco ASA? As the ping from your PC to the servers is actually working, I expect the routing to be in place correctly. Do you have ` sysopt connection permit-vpn` configured on the ASA? If not, have you added the required entries in the incoming ACL of the VPN terminating interface? //Just saw the question is one year old. I doubt that this is still relevant.